# Sharepoint 2010 - List name and column header display name change through XSL

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a site collection `(localhost)` that has two variations `(localhost/en/, localhost/fr/)`.

I have a list in the root web `(sampleList)` that has the following columns: `title`, `description`, `date`

I have English and French pages `(/en/samplePage.aspx, /fr/samplePage.aspx)` that uses `sampleList` as a shared web part.

Is there any way of modifying the web part on the French page (perhaps through the *XSL Link* field on the tool part) such that I can modify the list name and the column names of the list to be displayed in French?

Comment: When you say shared webpart you mean a content query webpart?

Comment: Nope, just dropped an existing list on the page (list view web part)

Comment: And when you change anything on this webpart it gets changed in the other variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that in SP Designer.  Here's a tutorial kinda what you need:
http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-customizing.html

You'll want to edit the page in designer ("edit in advanced mode") - then do steps 7 - 10 from the link.  After that, it'll be a matter of locating the references to the column names, removing them, then hard coding in new French names.

One word of caution, there's a tricky bugger related to `ddwrt:ghost="hide"` tags you'll see in the xslt.  Wherever you make changes, you'll probably need to find the preceding `ddwrt:ghost="hide"` and change it to `ddwrt:ghost=""` - or else you'll see your changes in desiger, but not in the actual site - you can read more about that here: http://www.sharepointbandaid.com/ddwrt/

In general, I usually had trouble do this, I preferred using the content query web part instead.  Also, hopefully this all makes sense, I haven't been in-front of SharePoint for awhile so I'm working from memory (which ain't what it used to be).

Comment: Thanks. I figured SP Designer would have to be used in this. What I ended up doing was creating a modified view for the French variation using http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/how-to-change-column-title-for-a-view-but-not-modify-the-list